# Ajax form post issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

I'm using Godaddy form email url to send email from form in hosted page. Form posts fields to "gdform.php", it sends email and redirects to my page. There is not any problem when it posts and redirects. Since it refreshes/loads page again I want to post form with ajax. When I use ajax I can't get any email. I compared request and response headers. After I put some headers now they show same request/response data. I can get a response from ajax request which is the redirected page content. That means form successfully sent to gdform.php and redirected to my page.
I couldn't understand why ajax form post doesn't work to send email even it makes successful post and get response.

// Contact form

```
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="gdform.php">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="email" name="email">
<textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Form Submission" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="index.html" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_order" value="alpha"/>
<input type="hidden" name="form_interval" value="default"/>
<input type="hidden" name="form_format" value="html"/>
</form>
```

// Contact form js

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        headers: { "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
                    Accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend(form_status.html('Email is sending...'));
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log("done " + data);
        form_status.html('Thank you for contact us.');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not including the data with your post request.

Include the "data" attribute in the object you pass to .ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    headers: { "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
                Accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: someData, # <----------HERE
    beforeSend: function(){
        form.prepend(form_status.html('Email is sending...'));
    }
})
```

You will need to collate this from the dom elements that you want to send. I think you can do this with .serialize(), like:

```
let someData = $('#main-contact-form').serialize();
```

Comment: Adding "data: $(this).serialize()," solved it. Thank you